# Looking for a expression that show me true for keywords inside a value

Tags: openrefine

I want a expression that filter keywords inside a text value.

I created this expression:

or(value.contains('ONIBUS'), value.contains('ÔNIBUS'), value.contains('COLETIVO'), value.contains('DENTRO'))

But i want something like this:

if(or(value.contains('ONIBUS'), value.contains('ÔNIBUS'), value.contains('COLETIVO'), value.contains('DENTRO')) and value.notcontains('DESCENDO'), TRUE, FALSE)

Create a Column

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.